# Syntax error when declaring column TIME WITH TIME ZONE

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, timezone, h2

I'm using H2 as an in memory database for a Spring Boot project, the java code declaration is the following:

```
@Column(name = "dueTime")
private OffsetTime dueTime;
```

in the H2 SQL migration file, I used the following instruction to add the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE TASK ADD COLUMN DUE_TIME TIME WITH TIME ZONE;
```

but I encountered a syntax error for the sentence `WITH TIME ZONE`;

my question is: how can I declare a column in H2 to hold time (with no date) with timezone information in order to serialize/de-serialize the Java type `OffsetTime` ?

PS: I tried the `TIME` declaration but I found time with no time zone information.

Best Regards.